# Can a Slave do Insert and Update on the master database?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have project and it's an Online Shop thingy. My professor said that I should not upload the Backend (The admin module) on the host server, that I should only upload the frontend (buying page, the pages the customers should only see.)

He also said that if there are any changes (such as customer inserted an order, the customer updated his profile...) on the online database, it should sync on the offline database (on my computer). And if there are any changes on the offline database, it should sync on the online database as well. It should work vice versa.

Then I saw articles about MySql Replication. The slave and the master thingy. I thought it would be a great solution to my problem... but my question is, can the slave (online part) can alter the database (offline part) directly? Because this project is an online shop so the data is always exchanging and data should always be updated on the admin and the customer..

Or is MySql replication the best solution? Or maybe something else.
(I also read that yeah, the slave can do insertion but if the table has an auto_increment, it would mess up the database.)

Any suggestion would be a really big help.
Thank you.

Comment: Your professor has some odd ideas.

Comment: That's his idea and he suggested such solution to prevent data loss. He thought that what if the online database went down, then I still have a backup of the data which is on the offline database. That's what he said.

Comment: Backing up a database server regularly is simple. This sort of approach makes little sense as a backup, and replication is **not** a backup, as queries that caused data loss would replicate!